Proof of a result concerning limits of subsequences
I attempted to prove a result related to limits of subsequences so here is the theorem:
Theorem: Let $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=L$ and $a_{n_k}$ be a subsequence of $a_n$. Then $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k}=L$
Proof:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=L$$
$$\Rightarrow \ \forall V \  a  \ neighborhood \ of \ L, \ \exists N\in\mathbb{N} \ such \ that \ a_n \in V \ whenever \ n>N$$
We pick a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers $n_k$ which tends to infinity as k gets larger. Mathematically:
$$\exists K \in \mathbb{N}, \ k>K, \ n_k>N, \ \forall N \in \mathbb{N}$$
Picking N to be the N in the definition of the convergence of $a_n$ we get:
$$\exists K \in \mathbb{N},\  whenever \ k>K, \ a_{n_k} \in V$$
Therefore:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k}=L$$
Is this proof considered a correct proof?
The reason I used the notion of neighborhoods to prove this theorem is because this is an exercise in Bert Mendelson's Introduction to Topology. So I had to use the notion of neighborhoods rather than concepts in real analysis.

The idea behind your proof is correct. However, not all such $n_k$ as you described form a valid subsequence. What we need is not the condition that $n_k \to \infty$ as $k\to \infty$, but instead that $n_k$ is strictly increasing, which (as a function on the naturals) implies the former. We can then deduce by induction that $n_k \geq k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Edit: Looking at it closer, the order of your quantifiers is strange. The fourth line should read $$\forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists K \in \mathbb{N}, k > K \Rightarrow n_k > N.$$ We put the N quantifier first as our choice of $K$ must depend on $N$ - there is no choice of $K$ that works for all $N$. Also, you shouldn't combine symbolic logic with English words - for your sixth line, either rewrite as $$\exists K \in \mathbb{N}, k > K \Rightarrow a_{n_k} \in V$$ or as "there exists a natural number $K$ such that whenever $k > K$, we have $a_{n_k} \in V$."
If you wanted to shorten your proof, instead of stating the existence of such a $K$ in the fourth line, we can note that specifically $K=N$ works, and so $$k > N \Rightarrow n_k > N \Rightarrow a_{n_k} \in V$$ by definition of $N$.

So you say that I must assume that $n_k$ is a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers which implies that $n_k \rightarrow \infty$

@AhmedHamdi This is the definition of a subsequence.

I know I guess I wasn't rigorous enough I assumed that this is the case but didn't state that explicitly. I will correct the post

@AhmedHamdi please check my edit

Ok sorry I am learning math in two languages and it's confusing to switch between both while writing a statement or a proof so forgive me for abuse of notation and mathematical language.

@AhmedHamdi no moral judgement, just trying to help! if you find my answer helpful i would be happy if you could accept it
